# How does Concerted Effort scale?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, bard

> **Concerted Effort**
>   ...
>   *Effect:* Until the end of your next turn, each target gains a +1 power bonus to attack rolls. Whenever a target hits with at least one attack during his or her turn, the bonus increases by 1 for each target whose turn has not yet started.

If the power affects the user and 4 allies, and all 4 allies hit with attacks on their turn, what bonus will the user have on their next turn?

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange.  While you are here you might want to take a [tour of the help section](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour).  Enjoy your stay.

Answer (score 2):

#### The bard would have a +5 power bonus.

The power bonus starts at +1 when Concerted Effort is used. It increases by 1, to +2, when the first ally hits. It increases by 1 again, to +3, when the second ally hits. It increases by 1 another time, to +4, when the third ally hits. Finally it increases by 1 for the last time when the fourth ally hits, to +5.

+1(start) +1(ally1) +1(ally2) +1(ally3) +1(ally4) = +5