# Does WotC have an official contact address for rules questions?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizards-of-the-coast

I asked [a question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100754/23970) but my GM says they need an "official" reply from WotC. Where should I send the question?

I can't find a general D&D Q&A "mailbox" or a specific D&D 4e Q&A one.

Answer (score 20):

Go to: https://wizards.custhelp.com/app/ask, Login or create an account, then select the appropriate product, then fill in the needed info.

They should get back to you.

Comment: Note for those who don't know: This ^^ guy is the [D&D Adventurers League Community Manager](http://dndadventurersleague.org/contact-us/campaign-staff/), so this is about as official an answer as you could dream of.

Answer (score 2):

Not any more.  Wizards of the Coast has moved on to 5th edition, and in their tradition they [ceased](https://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2295/) all rule support of old editions:

> Game Support no longer answers rules questions about the 4th edition of Dungeons & Dragons.

[Adventurer's League](http://dnd.wizards.com/playevents/organized-play) and [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums), for example, specifically runs on and only on fifth edition.  In fact, the many official blogs that discussed the creations and intentions of the rules has also been (re)moved, nowhere to be found.

5e did make some new support channels, however, by [closing the old forums](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/142474-Wizards-of-the-Coast-to-Close-Official-D-D-and-Magic-Forums).   The official [D&D twitter account](https://twitter.com/Wizards_DnD) is known to answer 4e rule questions as recently as [2016 Feb](https://twitter.com/Wizards_DnD/status/695658053178413057).

The question is pretty simple, however, and the power is not overpowered per se (a daily that average to around +2 for one turn considering misses is not much), so the real problem may be what the DM thinks about the power.  As the DM, (s)he doesn't really need an official rules to decide how things work in his campaign.